# limit of string values in a hashset while generating random values

Tags: java

**Code :**

```
public class setExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
    HashSet<String> hs1 = new HashSet<String>();

    int i;
    long startTime = 0,midTime = 0;
    long endTime = 0, difference, diff;


    startTime = System.nanoTime();

    for(i = 0; i < 10000000 ; i++)
    {
        hs.add(i+"");
    }

    ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>(hs);
    Collections.sort(arraylist);
    endTime = System.nanoTime();
    difference = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Time taken for sorted values in hashset is " +difference);

    midTime = System.nanoTime();
    for(i = 0; i < 10000000 ; i++)
    {
        hs1.add((int)(Math.random()*100000000)+"");
    }
    ArrayList<String> arraylist1 = new ArrayList<String>(hs1);
    Collections.sort(arraylist);
    long endTime1 = System.nanoTime();
    long difference1 = endTime1 - midTime;
    System.out.println("Time taken for random values in hashset is " +difference1);
}}
```

When running the above code I get the following output. Why is that random strings generated are having a problem ?

**Output:**

```
Time taken for sorted values in hashset is 14334316768
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.Integer.toString(Integer.java:308)
    at java.lang.Integer.toString(Integer.java:118)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2931)
    at learn.setExample.main(setExample.java:43)
```

Comment: Increase your heap using -Xmx java parameter. Like `-Xmx512m`

Comment: Your JVM is running out of memory. Can you limit your internal count to a minimal or increase your heap size?

Comment: It looks like you are interested in micro benchmarking.You may want to have a look at jmh (http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) to see what you are getting yourself into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As both the hash set are having lifespan till the end of the program
>   and hence the data added into hash set is also not available for the
>   garbage collection, hence you may end up getting the outofmememory
>   error.

Most importantly we are looking into the String pool, where we have added so many string, and as stringpool will keep on increasing based on number of String object created, hence the final solution could be increasing the heap size by configuring -Xmx512m.